# MSVS2017, Boost C++ error with namespaces

Tags: c++, windows, boost, visual-studio-2017

Can anyone help me out. I stumbled into a roadblock.

I've modified the project properties to include the Boost header path, and Boost linker path--plus the 'not using predefined header files' options'

Some how, Visual studio can't see std_in/std_out as part of the boost::process namespace.

I've compile the same file on Linux, and it works fine. Same version of Boost 1.78.0.

```
namespace bp = ::boost::process;


bp::opstream chldInput;
bp::ipstream chldOutput;

bp::child c(cmd.c_str(), bp::std_out > chldInput, bp::std_in < chldOutput);
```

Comment: Please add the complete text of the error. Emphasis on text. Don't take a picture of the Error list, instead switch from the Error List tab to the Output tab and copy the contents into your question.

Comment: Would seem a missing include.

Comment: Is your problem solved? Can you provide a [complete, minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @sehe, nope. It's included. I tried including the convenience headers, but doesn't work. I have include the specific headers.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT Will do! Hang tight...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that it can't see `bp::std_in` and `bp::std_out`. It's because you've swapped the streams.

- [`ipstream`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/process/basic_ipstream.html) is an implementation of a reading pipe stream - a stream that you can use in a similar way as `std::istream`s, like `std::cin`.
- [`opstream`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/process/basic_opstream.html) is an implementation of a write pipe stream - a stream that you can use in a similar way as `std::ostream`s, like `std::cout`.

However, `bp::std_out` needs to go to a `bp::ipstream` (which you then can read from) and `bp::std_in` needs its input from an `bp::opstream` (that you can write to).

Example:

```cpp
bp::child c(cmd.c_str(), bp::std_out > chldOutput, bp::std_in < chldInput);
```

Since `chldInput` isn't connected to anything, you may want to use `stdin` instead:

```cpp
bp::child c(cmd.c_str(), bp::std_out > chldOutput, bp::std_in < stdin);
```

You may also want to `c.wait()` for the command to finish.

Swapping the streams like you've done will likely generate an error like

```
program.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
program.cpp: error: no match for ‘operator>’ (operand types are ‘const boost::process::detail::std_out_<1>’ and ‘boost::process::opstream’ {aka ‘boost::process::basic_opstream<char>’})
      |     bp::child c(cmd.c_str(), bp::std_out > chldInput, bp::std_in < chldOutput);
      |                              ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~
      |                                  |         |
      |                                  |         boost::process::opstream {aka boost::process::basic_opstream<char>}
      |                                  const boost::process::detail::std_out_<1>
```

(and a few hundred lines more).

Comment: Wow. Solid lead. Quite a stretch from the question as posed, but it makes a lot of sense. +1